# Counting adjacent -1s in a 2d array for a given row/column without checking positions out of bounds

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Need help figuring out a different way to write count(), it's something that will add to my code here:

```
public class Grid
{
    private int [][] array;
    private int max;

    public Grid(int max)
    {
        array = new int[10][10];
        this.max = max;
        setRandom();

    }

    public void setRandom()
    {
        int i = 0;
        while(i < max)
        {
            int r = (int)(Math.random() * 9) + 0;
            int c = (int)(Math.random() * 9) + 0;
            if(array[r][c] != -1)
                {
                    array[r][c] = -1;
                    i++;
                }
        }
    }
    
    public void print()
    {
        for(int r = 0; r < array.length; r++)
        {
            for(int c = 0; c < array[r].length; c++)
            {
                System.out.print(array[r][c] + " ");
            }
                System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public int count(int row, int col)
    {
    // method here
    }
        
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Grid a = new Grid(20);
        a.count(5, 5);
        a.print();
    }
}
```

I want `count()` to return the number of -1s found in the 2d array surrounding the input position, and it also must not check a position "outside the bounds" (more specifically, the positions that aren't adjacent for a given row/column). Essentially it's like Minesweeper in a sense: let's say I pass in `count(5, 5)` (`5` being the row and column respectively), it will check all adjacent positions surrounding `(5, 5)`.

In this case, the highlighted blue is the position being checked and the yellow are adjacent positions. The white area is out of bounds and won't be checked. The position `(5, 5)` gets a value of 3 since there are **3** -1's surrounding the position. Visual here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DXVb.jpg

I came up with this code:

```
    public int count(int row, int col)
        {
            int value = 0;
            for(int r = -1; r < 2; r++)
            {
                for(int c = -1; c < 2; c++)
                {
                    if(c == 0 & r == 0)
                        continue;
                    if(array[row + r][col + c] == -1)
                    {
                        value++;
                    }
                }
            }
            return value;
        }
```

but when I pass in `a.count(4, 7)` in `main()`, nothing happens to the grid and it stays the same. I also want to find a different way to go about this without using `continue`
This is the output:

```
0 0 -1 -1 0 -1 0 0 0 0 
-1 0 0 -1 -1 0 -1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
-1 0 -1 0 0 0 0 -1 -1 0 
0 0 -1 -1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 -1 0 -1 0 0 0 -1 0 
0 0 -1 0 0 0 0 -1 0 0 
0 0 -1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

and I want my expected output to look something like this (if I passed in `a.count(4, 7)` - `4` being the row, `7` being the column)

```
0 0 -1 -1 0 -1 0 0 0 0 
-1 0 0 -1 -1 0 -1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
-1 0 -1 0 0 0 0 -1 -1 0 
0 0 -1 -1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 -1 0 -1 0 0 0 -1 0 
0 0 -1 **4** 0 0 0 -1 0 0 
0 0 -1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

(the 4 is the value in the position I passed in - since there are 4 -1s surrounding it, `(3, 7)` has a value of 4)

Comment: does the code I answered logically solves the problem correctly?

Comment: It looks good but I'm not sure why my grid is not changing and not adding a value to a position, it just stays the same as the sample output

Comment: `count()` method is not changing the grid in anyway. I think you wanted to call `setRandom()` method to change the grid.

Comment: I thought that's what the constructor for `Grid` already does: in the constructor, `setRandom()` is there after I initialized `max`. In main, I did the line `Grid a = new Grid(20)`

Comment: The grid randomizes -1s everytime I run it, it's just that no new value is added when I pass in a position with `count()`

Comment: `count()` doesn't contain any line that will add a new value to it. so why would you expect that to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check both the indices of row and column that you are trying to access is valid or not
Just add a check to prevent ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

```java
public int count(int row, int col) {
        int value = 0;
        for(int r = -1; r < 2; r++) {
            for(int c = -1; c < 2; c++) {
                if(c == 0 & r == 0)
                        continue;
                int newR = row + r;
                int newC = col + c;

                if(newR < 0 || newR >= array.length || newC < 0 || newC >= array[0].length)
                    continue;
                
                if(array[newR][newC] == -1)
                    value++;
            }
        }
        return value;
    }
```

**This is what I could come up with to avoid continue**

```java
     public int count(int row, int col) {
        int value = 0;
        value += isValidIndex(row - 1, col - 1)? array[row - 1][col - 1]: 0;
        value += isValidIndex(row - 1, col)? array[row - 1][col]: 0;
        value += isValidIndex(row - 1, col + 1)? array[row - 1][col + 1]: 0;
        value += isValidIndex(row, col - 1)? array[row][col - 1]: 0;
        value += isValidIndex(row, col + 1)? array[row][col + 1]: 0;
        value += isValidIndex(row + 1, col - 1)? array[row + 1][col - 1]: 0;
        value += isValidIndex(row + 1, col)? array[row + 1][col]: 0;
        value += isValidIndex(row + 1, col + 1)? array[row + 1][col + 1]: 0;
        return -value;
    }

    public boolean isValidIndex(int row, int col) {
        return !(row < 0 || col < 0 || row >= array.length || col >= array[0].length);
    }
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without continue?

Comment: we can avoid continue but the code doesn't look good. Using continue makes the code more readable